# Every chain complex is quasi-isomorphic to a $\mathcal J$-complex

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I found this in "Algebra & Topology" by Schapira, but I'm not able to prove it:

> Suppose $\mathcal J$ is a cogenerating family in an abelian category $\mathbf A$. Then for any positive complex $X^\bullet\in \text{Ch}(\mathbf A)$ the exists a positive complex made by  $\mathcal J$-objects, and a quasi isomorphism $X^\bullet\to J^\bullet$.

I can prove it assuming an additional hypothesis, namely $\mathcal J$ closed by subobjects, and I can't find a reference in any book I have...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My favorite construction is due to Bernhard Keller, *Chain complexes and stable categories*, Lemma 4.1 b) on page 14; the article is available on [his webpage](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~keller/publ/) (the lemma is formulated using injectives, but injectivity is not used in the argument). I've given the same argument for the dual situation with somewhat more details in Theorem 12.7 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1480v2).

(An alternative method would be to appeal to [Cartan–Eilenberg resolutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan-Eilenberg_resolution), which are treated in any sufficiently advanced homological algebra text I can think of, e.g. [Weibel](http://books.google.com/books?id=flm-dBXfZ_gC). The keywords to look for are “hyper-derived functors” and “hyperhomology”. Unfortunately, the usual expositions of the construction rely on injectivity, so these arguments need to be modified and I don't know of a reference for that.)

Let me also mention [Lemma 13.2.1, page 325](http://books.google.com/books?id=K-SjOw_2gXwC&pg=PA325) of Kashiwara–Schapira, *[Categories and Sheaves](http://books.google.com/books?id=K-SjOw_2gXwC)* for some variants of this result.

---

Here's Keller's construction:

Embed $X^0$ into a $\mathcal{J}$-object and form the push-out

```
X^0 -----> X^1
 V          V
 |          |
 |          |
 V          V
J^0 -----> Y^1
```

The differential $X^1 \to X^2$ factors over a unique morphism $Y^1 \to X^2$ such that $J^0 \to Y^1 \to X^1$ is zero. 
Now embed $Y^1$ into $J^1$ and form the push-out under that morphism and $Y^1 \to X^2$ and continue in this fashion to get:

```
X^0 -----> X^1
 V          V
 |          |
 |          |
 V          V
J^0 -----> Y^1 -----> X^2
            V          V
            |          |
            |          |
            V          V
           J^1 -----> Y^2 -----> X^3
                       V          V
                       |          |
                       |          |
                       V          V
                      J^2 -----> Y^3  etc.
```

The $J^n$ form a complex in an obvious way and there is a (degreewise monic) chain map $X^\bullet \to J^\bullet$. The fact that a square

```
      d
 A ------> B
 V         V
 |         |
 | i       | j
 V    e    V
 C ------> D
```

is a push-out if and only if the diagonal sequence

```
   [ d]
   [-i]      [j e]
A -----> B+C -----> E
```

is short exact exhibits the mapping cone of this chain map $X^\bullet \to J^\bullet$ as an acyclic complex, hence we have the desired quasi-isomorphism (you may have to fiddle a bit with the signs to make this harmonize with your favorite sign conventions).

Comment: The C-E construction is finer that this in that it «simultaneously resolves» $X$, its kernels and its homology. I can't tell if this construction does this.

Comment: Agreed, but it also is more complicated :) No, this argument doesn't do as much as the Cartan-Eilenberg construction. It only is a method to construct a distinguished triangle $X \to J \to A \to X[1]$ with $A$ acyclic.