# On equivalent definitions of Ext

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $A$ be an abelian category and $X$, $Y$ two objects of $A$. Let's define Ext in this way:

> Ext$^i_A(X,Y)$=Hom$_{D(A)}(X[0],Y[i])$

Where $X[0]$ is the complex with all zeros except in degree 0 where it has $X$, and $Y[i]$ is the complex with all zeros except in degree $-i$ where it has $Y$.

Now I would like to prove that this definition is equivalent to the usual definition of Ext, i.e.:

take a projective resolution of $X$: $\cdots\rightarrow P^{-1}\rightarrow P^0\rightarrow X\rightarrow 0$ then Ext$^n_A(X,Y)$ is the $n$th cohomology group of the complex $0\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(P^0,Y)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(P^{-1},Y)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(P^{-2},Y)\rightarrow\cdots$.

I have an hint: denote by $K(A)$ the homotopy category. It seems to be useful to prove that we have an isomorphism

> $\mathrm{Hom}_{K(A)}(X^\bullet,Y^\bullet)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_{D(A)}(X^\bullet,Y^\bullet)$ in the following cases:

1) $Y^\bullet\in\mathrm{Ob}\;Kom^+(I)$, i.e. $Y^\bullet$ is a bounded complex on the left of injectives objects;

2) $X^\bullet\in\mathrm{Ob}\;Kom^-(P)$, i.e. $X^\bullet$ is a bounded complex on the right of projective objects.

I'm pretty sure that we need only one between 1 and 2, and the other is useful if we want to prove the caracterization of Ext with injective resolutions, but I can do that if you could show me how to do it with projective resolutions.

By the way the map $\mathrm{Hom}_{K(A)}(X^\bullet,Y^\bullet)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_{D(A)}(X^\bullet,Y^\bullet)$ is $f\mapsto$ the equivalence class of the roof $X\leftarrow X\rightarrow Y$, where $id:X\rightarrow X$ and $f:X\rightarrow Y$.

And if you need the definition of roof just look to one of my previous questions: [why is this composition well defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184473/why-is-this-composition-well-defined)

Comment: Are you comfortable with the following? If $\mathcal{A}$ has enough projectives, then there is an equivalence $Q: Kom^b(P(\mathcal{A}))\to D^b(\mathcal{A})$ just by including the bounded complex of projectives into the bounded homotopy category and then the localization (inverting quasi-isos). Let $F:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ be a right exact functor. One way to *define* the total derived functor $\mathbf{L}F$ is via the composition $Q\circ \overline{F} \circ Q^{-1}$. Before writing an answer, do you believe this is equivalent to the way you've defined $Ext^i=H^i(\mathbf{L}Hom)$?

Comment: This is done in detail (assuming enough injectives) in I.§6 of Hartshorne's *Residues and duality*. @Matt: don't you need a finiteness condition on $\mathcal{A}$ such as "every object has a finite projective resolution" to reduce to *bounded* complexes?  Otherwise $Q$ will fail to be essentially surjective, even onto $\mathcal{A}$. I agree with the rest of what you say, of course.

Comment: To find for every right bounded complex a quasi-isomorphism from a right bounded complex of projectives  you can either use [Cartan-Eilenberg resolutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan–Eilenberg_resolution) (probably the preferred procedure for dealing with spectral sequences) or use [this simple construction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80513/) due to Keller (I describe the dual version).

Comment: @t.b. Yes. Of course. I was just assuming that situation to make the comment as short and easy to follow as possible.

Comment: @Matt: sorry Matt, I'm not so comfortable with what you said.

Comment: I just tried to write a proof for you and I realized something. You should define $Ext^i(X^\bullet, Y^\bullet)=Hom_{D(A)}(X^\bullet [0], Y^\bullet [i])$ for complexes and then prove for just single objects in $A$ otherwise $Ext$ won't be defined for enough things to write a proof.

Answer (score 11):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$The main point is that a projective resolution $\dots \to P^{-2} \to P^{-1} \to P^{0} \xrightarrow{\alpha^0} X$ gives you a quasi-isomorphism $\alpha \colon P^{\bullet} \to X[0]$. Indeed, the mapping cone of $\alpha$ is exact because it *is* the resolution (maybe up to an immaterial sign in the differentials).

A quasi-isomorphism becomes an isomorphism in the derived category (because that's what we invert), in particular precomposition with $\alpha^{-1}$ (or, if you prefer: composition with the roof $X[0] \xleftarrow{\alpha} P^\bullet \xrightarrow{1} P^\bullet$) gives an isomorphism $$\Hom\nolimits_{D(A)}(P^\bullet,Y) \xrightarrow{\cong} \Hom\nolimits_{D(A)}(X[0],Y) $$ for every complex $Y \in D(A)$.

From fact 2) of the question we have a composite isomorphism
$$
\Hom\nolimits_{K(A)}(P^\bullet,Y) \xrightarrow{\cong} \Hom\nolimits_{D(A)}(P^\bullet,Y) \xrightarrow{\cong} \Hom\nolimits_{D(A)}(X[0],Y)
$$
for all complexes $Y$ which is explicitly given by sending a (homotopy class of a) chain map $f\colon P^\bullet \to Y$ to the roof $X[0] \xleftarrow{\alpha} P^\bullet \xrightarrow{f} Y$, so it only remains to identify the complex $\Hom_{K(\mathscr{A})}(P^\bullet, Y)$.

I hope I got the signs and indices right in what is to follow: for any two complexes $A$ and $B$ over an additive category $\mathscr{A}$ one defines the total $\Hom$-complex $\Hom\nolimits^\bullet(A,B)$ of abelian groups by
$$
\Hom\nolimits^k(A,B) = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\Hom\nolimits_{\mathscr{A}}(A^n,B^{n+k})
$$
with differential $(f^n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \mapsto \left(f^{n+1}d_A^n-(-1)^{k}d_B^{n+k}f^n \right)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ and it is elementary to check (if indeed I got the signs right) that
$$\boxed{
H^k\left(\Hom\nolimits^\bullet(A,B)\right) = \Hom\nolimits_{K(\mathscr{A})}(A,B[k])
}$$
because in order for $f = (f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ to be a cycle in $\Hom\nolimits^k(A,B)$ it is necessary and sufficient that $f \colon A \to B[k]$ defines a chain map and to be a boundary means that it is homotopic to zero. (In the sign conventions I'm used to shifting a complex by $1$ involves multiplying its differentials by $-1$)

If we take $A = P^\bullet$ and $B=Y[0]$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ we see that the $\Hom$ complex collapses to $\Hom^k(P^{\bullet},Y[0]) = \Hom\nolimits_{\mathscr{A}}(P^{-k},Y)$ and computing its cohomology amounts to taking the cohomology of the complex
$$
\dots \to 0 \to \Hom\nolimits_{\mathscr{A}}(P^0,Y) \xrightarrow{d^\ast}
\Hom\nolimits_{\mathscr{A}}(P^{-1},Y) \xrightarrow{d^\ast}
\Hom\nolimits_{\mathscr{A}}(P^{-2},Y) \xrightarrow{d^\ast} \cdots
$$
which via
$$
\operatorname{Ext}^k(X,Y) = \operatorname{Hom}_{D(A)}(X,Y[k]) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{K(A)}(P^\bullet,Y[k]) = H^k(\operatorname{Hom}^\bullet(P^\bullet,Y[0]))
$$
gives the identification you ask about.

Comment: The next exercise would be to relate this to Matt's comment and for this I second the recommendation of consulting Hartshorne's residues and duality. The last chapter of Weibel's book also contains some useful things to know.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\A{\mathcal{A}}
\def\Ext{\operatorname{Ext}}$Here's the abstract-nonsense approach: one could verify both definitions you gave for $\Ext^i_\A(X,-)$ satisfy the same universal property. Namely, they both constitute a [$\delta$-functor](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/010Q) that is [universal](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/010S) (morphisms of $\delta$-functors are defined [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/010R)).

There is a sufficient condition that a $\delta$-functor can satisfy for it being universal. Namely, we say that a $\delta$-functor $(F^i)_{i\geq 0}$ is *erasable* (or *effaceable*, after Grothendieck coined *effaçable* in French in his Tôhoku paper) if for each $Y\in\operatorname{ob}\mathcal{A}$ and $i>0$ there is an injection $Y\to Z$ such that $F^iZ=0$. In Proposition 2.2.1 of the Tôhoku paper, Grothendieck showed that erasability implies universality (in the SP this is [010T](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/010T), and the result has been discussed several times in MSE, e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894776/showing-that-effaceable-delta-functors-are-universal), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/637231/394668)).

Suppose then $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives (so that we have a definition of $\Ext$ via injective resolutions). It is trivial to show that the definition of the $\Ext$ functors via injective resolutions, as a $\delta$-functor, is erasable. On the other hand, to see that $(\operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(X,(-)[i]))_{i\geq 0}$ is erasable, consider an object $Y$ of $\mathcal{A}$ and take an injection $Y\to I$ into an injective object. For $i>0$ and by [05TG](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05TG),

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(X,I[i])
=\operatorname{Hom}_{K(\mathcal{A})}(X,I[i])
=0.
\end{align*}

Dually, one shows that the contravariant $\delta$-functor $(\operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(-,Y[i]))_{i\geq 0}$ and the definition of $\Ext$ via projective resolutions are both coerasable.