# The projective model structure on chain complexes

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, model-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with enough projective objects and let $\mathcal{M}$ be the category of chain complexes in $\mathcal{A}$ concentrated in *non-negative degrees*. Quillen [1967, Ch. II, §4] asserts that the following data define a model structure on $\mathcal{M}$:

- The weak equivalences are the quasi-isomorphisms (= homology isomorphisms).
- The cofibrations are the monomorphisms with degreewise projective cokernels.
- The fibrations are the morphisms that are epic in positive degrees.

**Question.** Is there a direct proof of this fact in the literature, *in this generality*?

Quillen's proof goes via simplicial objects in $\mathcal{A}$ and the Dold–Kan correspondence.  All I have found so far are proofs in the case where $\mathcal{A}$ is the category of $R$-modules for a ring $R$, and these use the small object argument to construct factorisations.

Answer (score 18):

Apart from the two factorization axioms, the proof in [Dwyer-Spalinski](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Dwyer-Spalinski/theories.pdf)'s section 7 goes through in the desired generality and it doesn't make a detour via Dold-Kan. Therefore I'll only fill in the part of the argument depending on the small object argument in all the sources I know.

In order to produce factorizations without the small object argument, you can make use of the mapping cone and mapping cylinder constructions. I did this in [my thesis](http://www.ams.org/books/memo/1006/), Appendix C, for *bounded below complexes* in an exact category with enough projectives. For nonnegative complexes, essentially the same constructions work, but one faces the additional difficulty of making sure the complexes stay non-negative. I'm not aware that such an elementary proof is written up anywhere in the literature, but it is not too difficult...

The argument is a rather tedious exercise in homological algebra. The explicit nature of the construction shows that you can obtain functorial factorizations whenever there is a 'projective resolvent functor', that is to say, there is a functor $P \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{P}$ and an epimorphic natural transformation $P \Rightarrow \operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{A}}$.

---

We will use the following lemma:

> For every complex $A$ in $\mathcal{M}$ there is a degreewise epimorphic quasi-isomorphism $P \to A$, where $P$ is a complex with projective components.

A proof and references can be found here: [Every chain complex is quasi-isomorphic to a $\mathcal J$-complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80513)

---

Consider an arbitrary morphism $f \colon A \to B$ $\require{AMScd}$. We have  to produce the usual factorizations.

---

Let's start with the easier case:

Recall that the usual map $\operatorname{cyl}(f) \to B$ is degreewise surjective and a chain homotopy equivalence, in particular it is both a fibration and a weak equivalence. The inclusion $A \to \operatorname{cyl}(f)$ is close to being a cofibration, but its cokernel $\operatorname{cone}(f)$ isn't a complex with projective components.

To remedy this, choose a degreewise epimorphic quasi-isomorphism $p\colon P \to \operatorname{cone}(f)$ from a complex with projective components $P$, and let $q$ be the pullback of $p$ along the projection $\operatorname{cyl}(f) \to \operatorname{cone}(f)$. We obtain the following commutative diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
A @>i>> Q @>>> P \\
@| @V{\sim}VqV @V{\sim}VpV \\
A @>>> \operatorname{cyl}(f) @>>> \operatorname{cone}(f) \\
@| @V{\simeq}VV \\
A @>f>> B
\end{CD}
$$
Note that the first two rows are short exact and all vertical maps are degreewise epimorphic and weak equivalences (observe that $\operatorname{Ker}(q) = \operatorname{Ker}(p)$ is acyclic).

Thus, the map $i \colon A \to Q$ so constructed is a cofibration and the composition $Q \to \operatorname{cyl}(f) \to B$ is both a fibration and a weak equivalence.

---

The second factorization is a bit trickier. The main idea is to pass to the "Eckmann-Hilton dual" of the previous construction (the mapping cylinder is a homotopy push-out, its dual is a homotopy pull-back).

The hard work is to show that $f = qj$ where $q\colon D \to B$ is a fibration and $j \colon A \to D$ is a degreewise monic chain homotopy equivalence with contractible cokernel $E$.

Once this is shown, we can choose a degreewise surjective map $p \colon P \to E$ from a contractible complex $P$ with projective components and form the pull-back $Q = P \mathbin{\times_E} D$ as before to end up with the desired factorization $f = (qr)k$, where $k$ is a cofibration and a weak equivalence and $(qr)$ is a fibration:
$$
\begin{CD}
A @= A @= A \\
@V{k}V{\sim}V @V{j}V{\sim}V @VV{f}V \\
Q @>r>> D @>q>> B \\
@VVV @VVV \\
P @>p>> E
\end{CD}
$$
The above diagram is commutative and the first two columns are exact and all horizontal maps are fibrations.

---

Let us construct the claimed factorization of $f\colon A \to B$ into a monic chain homotopy equivalence $j \colon A \to D$ followed by a fibration $q\colon D \to B$.

In a first attempt, we factor $f \colon A \to B$ as $A \xrightarrow{i} C \xrightarrow{p} B$, where $i$ is a weak equivalence 'close to a cofibration' and $p$ is a fibration. Here $C$ is an appropriate version of the 'mapping path space' with the deficit that it might have a non-zero entry in degree $-1$. Explicitly,
let $C_n = A_n \oplus B_n \oplus B_{n+1}$ and $d_{n}^C = \begin{bmatrix} d_{n}^A & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & d_{n}^B & 0 \\ f_n & -1 & -d_{n+1}^B \end{bmatrix}$, where $C_{-1} = 0 \oplus 0 \oplus B_0$.

It is straightforward to verify that the chain map $i \colon A \to C$ with
components $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ f_n \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \colon A_n \to A_n \oplus B_n \oplus B_{n+1}$ is a chain homotopy equivalence. A homotopy inverse is given by the projection $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ onto the first summand of $C$. Also, the chain map $i$ is degreewise monic, and its cokernel can be computed to be the contractible complex $\operatorname{cone}(1_{B[-1]})$

The lower end of the factorization of $f$ looks like this (the complexes run vertically and degrees $2,1,0,-1$ are displayed):

$$
\begin{CD}
A_2 @>{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ f_2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}}>> 
A_2 \oplus B_2 \oplus B_3 @>{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}>> B_2 \\
@VV{d_{2}^A}V
@VV{\begin{bmatrix} d_{2}^A & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & d_{2}^B & 0 \\ f_2 & -1 & -d_{3}^B \end{bmatrix}}V
@VV{d_{2}^B}V \\
A_1 @>{i_1}>> 
A_1 \oplus B_1 \oplus B_2 @>{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}>> B_1 \\
@VV{d_{1}^A}V
@VV{\begin{bmatrix} d_{1}^A & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & d_{1}^B & 0 \\ f_1 & -1 & -d_{2}^B \end{bmatrix}}V
@VV{d_{1}^B}V \\
A_0 @>{i_0}>> 
A_0 \oplus B_0 \oplus B_1 @>{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}>> B_0 \\
@VVV @VV{\begin{bmatrix} f_0 & -1 & -d_{1}^B \end{bmatrix}}V
@VVV \\
0 @>>> B_0 @>>> 0 \\
\hline\\
A @>i>> C @>p>> B
\end{CD}
$$
Note that $f = pi$ and that $p$ is epimorphic in all degrees.

In order to get rid of the piece in degree $-1$, we replace $C$ by its good truncation $D = \tau_{\geq 0} C$, so

> $D_n = C_n = A_n \oplus B_n \oplus B_{n+1}$ for $n \geq 1$ and $D_0 = \operatorname{Ker}(d_0\colon C_0 \to C_{-1}) = A_0 \oplus B_1$.

The inclusion $D_0 \to C_0$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ f_0 & -d_{1}^B \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \colon A_0 \oplus B_1 \to A_0 \oplus B_0 \oplus B_1$.

Factoring everything in sight over $D_0$, the lower end of the sequence $A \xrightarrow{j} D \xrightarrow{q} B$ turns out to be

> $$
> \begin{CD}
> A_2 @>{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ f_2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}}>> 
> A_2 \oplus B_2 \oplus B_3 @>{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}>> B_2 \\
> @VV{d_{2}^A}V
> @VV{\begin{bmatrix} d_{2}^A & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & d_{2}^B & 0 \\ f_2 & -1 & -d_{3}^B \end{bmatrix}}V
> @VV{d_{2}^B}V \\
> A_1 @>{i_1}>> 
> A_1 \oplus B_1 \oplus B_2 @>{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}>> B_1 \\
> @VV{d_{1}^A}V
> @VV{\begin{bmatrix} d_{1}^A & 0 & 0 \\ f_1 & -1 & -d_{2}^B \end{bmatrix}}V
> @VV{d_{1}^B}V \\
> A_0 @>>{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}}> 
> A_0 \oplus B_1 @>>{\begin{bmatrix} f_{0} & -d_{1}^B \end{bmatrix}}> B_0 \\
> \hline \\
> A @>j>> D @>q>> B
> \end{CD}
> $$

Observe that $q$ is a fibration (it is an epimorphism except in degree zero) and that $f = qj$.

To finish up, note that $j$ is a degreewise monic chain homotopy equivalence whose cokernel is the complex $E_n = B_{n} \oplus B_{n+1}$ in degrees $n \geq 1$ and $E_0 = B_1$, the differential is given by the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} d^{B}_n & 0 \\ -1 & -d^{B}_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}$.

From here it's now easy to write down the complex $Q$ explicitly, but I'll leave that to the interested reader.

Comment: This is such an awesome answer

Comment: There is a simpler example for the second factorization. For a map $A \to B$, we can choose some epi $P \to B$ from a projective object (in this case, a split exact complex with projective objects in each degree). Then $A \to A \oplus P \to B$ is a factorization as a cofibration and weak equivalence followed by a fibration.