# Choosing projective replacement to be functorial

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, abelian-categories, derived-functors

A basic result of homological algebra says that if $\mathsf A$ is an abelian category with enough projectives, then the mapping $P:\mathsf{Obj}(\mathsf A)\rightarrow \mathsf{Obj}(\mathsf{K} ^+(\mathsf A))$ sending each object to the homotopy type of its projective resolutions almost lifts to a functor in the sense that $P(g\circ f)\cong P(g)\circ P(f)$.

> 1. Is there a general way to fix the "almost" functoriality of $P$? If not, are classical derived not actually functors?

In Riehl's [Categorical Homotopy Theory](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~eriehl/cathtpy.pdf), sec 2.3, the author says that in $R$-$\mathsf Mod$, a more refined process enables the replacement of any complex with a quasi-isomorphic complex of projectives. She then says that careful choice of projective resolution yields a proper functor $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet ^+(R)\rightarrow \mathsf{Ch}_\bullet ^+(R)$ along with a natural quasi-isomorphism $q:Q\Rightarrow 1$. In other words, projective replacement is a left deformation of the homotopical category $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet ^+(R)$ with q.i's as weak equivalences.

> 2. What is this "refined process" and "careful choice"?
> 3. What is a general condition on an abelian category with enough projectives that would ensure projective replacement become functorial and moreover a left deformation as in $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$?

In Remark 2.3.2, the author notes the absense of *functorial* deformations, the usual process of projective replacement defines *total* derived functors, but not point-set level derived functors.

> 4. What is meant by *functorial* deformations?

---

***Update:*** [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563021/the-projective-model-structure-on-chain-complexes?rq=1) seems to be related, but I don't see any conditions guaranteeing a "projective resolvent functor".

Comment: 1. Classical derived functors are functors – between the derived categories. 2. Look up Cartan–Eilenberg resolutions. 3. A functorial projective replacement should be enough. 4. There is only one possible meaning.

Comment: @ZhenLin regarding (2), one of the first googles is [the stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/015G). There it proven in particular that projective replacement exists. In remark 13.21.4 it is said that this replacement is functorial, but I don't see why this is true at all. (I don't know anything about spectral sequences.) Regarding (3), I was trying to ask for conditions on an abelian category that would ensure functoriality. On another note, if you would post your comment as a more detailed answer I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Derived functors are functors. What is your confusion? You divide out the chain homotopy relation in the target category.

2,3. In order to construct a functorial projective resolution you need to have for each object A in the abelian category a natural surjection from a projective object $P_A \to A$.

4. This is similar to functorial cofibrant replacements.

In most practical situations the functoriality exists. I'll give you one example where it does not: consider the abelian category of finitely generated abelian groups, then there enough projectives, but there is no way to choose them functorially.